# How to consume classic ASP.NET web service in windows phone application 8.1?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, windows-phone-8.1

How can I write a code to consume classic ASP.NET and WCF web service in windows phone 8.1 application?

Its not allowing me to add service reference in solution explorer.

Comment: What do you mean, "it is not allowing me to add service reference" ? Do you get an error message ? Do you not have the option ?

Comment: i didnt found any option to add service reference in VS2013 Community as we have in VS2010.

Comment: If Add Service Reference isn't available, you can always use [SvcUtil.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733(v=vs.110).aspx) to generate a proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/893352/Using-WCF-Service-in-Windows-Phone) will help you in setting up a web service. 
But in Windows Phone 8.1 Microsoft has started urging developers to use REST services more.

Comment: Right-click on References and select Add Service Reference. Is not allowed in VS2013 Community.

Comment: Yes Thats why I added the lines about REST services. Since Service Reference isnt allowed you can call your data asynchronously using REST services.